# Disable Document ID in Drop-off library

Tags: content-organizer, document-id, records-center

I am implementing a Records Center, and we are using the Content Organizer to place the items/records in the appropriate libraries. Document IDs are an important feature to provide permanent links functionality, so it is activated for the Records Center.

The Document ID relies on two mechanisms to retrieve a record: a) Directly addressing the record through the library and item number defined in the ID or, if it fails because the item was moved, b) SharePoint search.

As items are first placed in the Drop-off library, the Document ID is assigned there. When the item gets automatically moved to the final destination library (shortly after), the Document-ID is still pointing to the Drop-off library.

As a result, the direct Document ID retrieval method mechanism never works! We are always dependent on search, which means that the Document ID will not work until the next crawl, that when a user is added or removed to a permission group for a library, the access change will not be reflected until the next crawl etc.

I cannot see why would Microsoft assign a permanent Document ID on a transfer library (Drop-Off) in the first place!

Is there a way to disable the Document ID for the Drop-off library? If not, can we assign a new Document ID in the other libraries?

Comment: Have you tried to create an event receiver and duplicate the item creating a new ID for the destination library when copying or moving the original one if need be? This is the only way I can see of properly removing the linking behavior you are getting.

Comment: Btw this is because the ID is the unique field and is required.

Answer (score 2):

Marco, this is unfortunately functionality you need to "live" with. We created our own unique document ID service application that ensures document ID's are maintained through the lifecycle even when moved to the records centre. We also created a configuraiton page to allow unique numbering to be set at a content type level therefore you are not restricted by a Site Collection ID and the constraints around your IA. This is also a farm wide unique ID service.